# I have 40 columns and I want to concatenate every 2 columns of those 40 columns into 2 columns by using a loop

Tags: python

How do I load the data and rearrange them so that x of shape (2000, 2) values and y of shape (2000,) that represent the labels?

This is what I am currently doing now.
This is the info I know:

**The dataframe has
100 rows × 40 columns**

so I

```
p1 = q2_data.iloc[:,0:2]
p2 = q2_data.iloc[:,2:4]
.......
p20 = q2_data.iloc[:,38:40]

new_columns = ["x1", "x2"]

p1.columns = new_columns
p2.columns = new_columns
.....
p40.columns = new_columns

print( pd.concat([p1, p2,.....,p20], ignore_index=True))
```

> [2000 rows x 2 columns]

How do I also had labels to each of the columns of p1, p2, .. p40? so I can create another column with labels ranging form (0,19)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the loop logic, this probably works, not the best looking script tho.

```
columns_name = ["x1", "x2"] # initiate the column name
new_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns_name) # create an empty dataframe with column name

for col_index in range(0,len(q2_data.columns))[::2]: # create a loop with sliding windows of 2
    temp = q2_data.iloc[:,col_index:col_index+2] # create a temporary df to store the value
    
    temp.rename(dict(zip(list(temp.columns), columns_name)), inplace = True) # rename for concatenating purpose
    
    new_df = pd.concat([new_df, temp], ignore_index = True)
```